# Loading template with variables from form fields using jQuery & php

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a form that generates an html template. I have the template in a hidden div on the page and am using jQuery to create a new window with the template html, but I can't figure out how to load the contents of the form fields into the template. I know I should probably be using AJAX, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this template:

```
<div class="template">
    <p class="blah"></p>
    <p class="foo"></p>
</div>
```

and this form:

```
<form>
    <input name="blah" class="blah"/>
    <input name="foo" class="foo"/>
</form>
```

so, for this example we will assume a mapping of form elements to template elements via a common class for each corresponding element:

```
$("form input").each(function() {
    $(".template").find("." + $(this).attr("class")).html(this.value);
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/dx2E6/

Answer (score 0):

One trick I've been using is using the `<script type="text/html">` tag. The browser doesn't render the code, so what I do is something like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
<div>
  <div class="some_field">{name}</div>
  <h4>{heading}</h4>
  <p>{text}</p>
</div>
</script>
```

Your form  is something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="heading" />
  <input type="text" name="text" />
</form>
```

Then your javascript code would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var tpl = $('#template').html();

  $('form input').each(function(){
    tpl.replace('{'+$(this).attr('name')+'}',$(this).val());
  });

  $('div.some_destination').html(tpl);

});
```

Hope it helps. Tell me if you have more questions regarding this method.